# Is my interpretation about the outer product representation correct?

Tags: quantum-state

If it is said that an $n$-qubit system is initially prepared in the product state $$ \rho_0 = |0\rangle \langle0|^{\otimes n} $$
Does that mean $\rho $ acts as an operator on every qubit and initializes them to $|0\rangle$?

Comment: Are you familiar with density matrix formalism? Here $\rho$ is the state of $n$ qubits. $\rho$ is not some operator acting on the state. I would suggest reading about density matrices if you are not familiar with them. It will make things clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

> If it is said that an $n$-qubit system is initially prepared in the product state $$ \rho_0 = |0\rangle \langle0|^{\otimes n} $$

> Does that mean $\rho $

Here, you have switched to using the symbol $\rho$ rather than $\rho_0$, but I think you still mean $\rho_0$.

> acts as an operator on every qubit and initializes them to $|0\rangle$?

Your $\rho_0$ does not necessarily "act" on anything, unless you let it.

However, if you *were* to act with your $\rho_0$ operator on an arbitrary ket (vector in Hilbert space), it would project out the $|000\ldots 0 \rangle$ component.

This should be obvious from looking at the matrix representation:
$$
\rho_0 \to \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
\otimes \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
\otimes \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
\ldots
\otimes \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: What do you mean $\rho$ isn't a state? Of course it is! Or at least it represents a state just as much as a ket represents a state [eg wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)

Comment: I would normally use the word "state" to refer to a vector in Hilbert space (up to a phase). But it looks like this is not correct (for a non-pure state) or clear, which is reflected in the link you gave.

Comment: Anyways, I removed that part.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Sorry, didn't tag you. Yes, of course, you are right.

Comment: no problem, just making sure everything is clear